# Multi-mode XML processors for Java and/or Scala

Tags: java, xml, scala

One of benefits of using Jackson for JSON processing is:

> [all modes [i.e. streaming, tree, and binding to Java objects] fully supported, and best of all, in such a way that it is easy to convert between modes, mix and match. For example, to process very large JSON streams, one typically starts with a streaming parser, but uses data binder to bind sub-sections of data into Java objects: this allows processing of huge files without excessive memory usage, but with full convenience of data binding.](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/11/entry_434.html)

Are there XML processors for Java or Scala which also support this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to check out Smooks

http://smooks.org

HTH